# Why was "immediate" attribute added to the EditableValueHolders?

Tags: jsf, design-decisions, immediate-attribute

Initially `immediate` flag was only intended for `ActionSource` interface. But later on it was added to the `EditableValueHolder` interface also.   What was the reason for design decision ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's to be used to prioritize validation on several `EditableValueHolder` components in the same form.

Imagine a form containing input components with `immediate="true"` as well as input components without this attribute. The immediate inputs will be validated during apply request values phase (which is one phase earlier than usual). The non-immediate inputs will be validated during validations phase (which is the usual phase). If validation fails for at least one of the immediate inputs, then the non-immediate inputs won't be converted/validated at all and thus won't generate any conversion/validation error messages. This is particularly useful in forms with complex validation rules where it doesn't make sense to validate component Y when validation for (immediate) component X has failed anyway.

When used in combination with `immediate="true"` on a command button in the same form, this will cause all non-immediate inputs being completely skipped. A good real world example is a login form with 2 fields "username" and "password" with `required="true"` and 2 buttons: "login" and "password forgotten". You could put `immediate="true"` on the "username" field and the "password forgotten" button to skip the `required="true"` check on the password field.

In the dark JSF 1.x ages, the `immediate="true"` was also often (ab)used as a hack in combination with `valueChangeListener` and `FacesContext#renderResponse()`, more than often in cascading dropdown lists. Long story short, here's an [old blog article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/10/populate-child-menus.html) on that. To the point, it enables developers to execute a backing bean method on change of a `<h:selectOneMenu>` without that all other inputs in the same form are been validated. But these days, with the ajax awesomeness, this hack is unnecessary. You can find a concretre example of this case at the bottom of [our `<h:selectOneMenu>` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info).

These days, the `immediate="true"` is still often (ab)used in order to have a specific button which completely bypasses all other inputs, such as a logout button in a "God-form" antipattern (whereby *everything* is been thrown together in a huge `<h:form>`), or a cancel button which incorrectly submits the form. Such a button would break when you start to actually need the `immediate="true"` the right way on one of the inputs. You'd better put such a logout button in its own form, or to change it to process only itself (`process="@this"` in PrimeFaces). And you'd better change such a cancel button to just refresh the page synchronously by `<h:button value="Cancel" />`. This works fine if the form is tied to a request/view scoped bean and browser caching is [disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305718/avoid-back-button-on-jsf-web-application/) on dynamic pages.

#### See also:

- [Should immediate="true" never be used when dealing with an AJAXified JSF 2.0 component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502326/should-immediate-true-never-be-used-when-dealing-with-an-ajaxified-jsf-2-0-com)
- [Trying to understand immediate="true" skipping inputs when it shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960718/trying-to-understand-immediate-true-skipping-inputs-when-it-shouldnt/)