# How to set JSF input field value before submit

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I a have a JSF page with PrimeFaces with some input fields. Before a submit is done, I would like to use the value of a field as input for a method which does some calculations and updates another field with the result but without submitting the form.

This is the field that will be used as input for my method:

```
<h:outputLabel for="hiredate" value="#{msgs['addUser.hireDate']}" />
                                <p:calendar id="hiredate" value="#{userWizardMB.user.hireDate}" required="true" immediate="true"/>
                                <p:message for="hiredate" />
```

The calculation is done by clicking a `<p:commandButton>`:

```
<p:commandButton value="Calculate days" icon="ui-icon-circle-check" action="#{userWizardMB.calculateVacationDays}" update="vacationDays" process="@this" immediate="true"/>
```

And this is the method called:

```
public void calculateVacationDays() {
        user.setVacationDays((int) vacationDaysCalculator
                .calculateWithHireDate(user.getHireDate()));
}
```

When debugging, though, I see that this field is NULL even if I set value in the form.

How can I force the setting of this field - user.hireDate because I really need this value for my calculation?

Thank you

**Edit:** I removed all of the other fields in the form and the immediate attribute:

```
<h:form id="addUserForm">
    <p:wizard widgetVar="wizard" flowListener="#{userWizardMB.onFlowProcess}">
                <!-- TAB FOR PERSONAL DATA -->
                    <p:tab id="personal" title="#{msgs['addUser.personalTab']}">
                        <p:panel header="#{msgs['addUser.personalInformation']}">
                            <p:message for="vacationDays" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true"/>
                            <h:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="label, value" styleClass="grid">

                                <h:outputLabel for="hiredate" value="#{msgs['addUser.hireDate']}" />
                                <p:calendar id="hiredate" value="#{userWizardMB.user.hireDate}" required="true" />
                                <p:message for="hiredate" />


                                <h:outputLabel for="vacationDays" value="#{msgs['addUser.vacationDays']}"/>
                                <p:inputText id="vacationDays" value="#{userWizardMB.user.vacationDays}"/>
                                <p:commandButton value="Calculate days" icon="ui-icon-circle-check" action="#{userWizardMB.calculateVacationDays}"  process="@this hiredate" update="vacationDays"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </p:tab>
    </p:wizard>
</h:form>
```

And the backing bean method is still not called.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `immediate="true"` from the input and the command component. Do not use `immediate` unless you *really* understand what it should be used for. Further you also need to include the input component which you'd like to process in the `update` attribute of the command component. Note that this should represent the client ID, not the property name as mentioned in one of your comments.

```
<p:calendar id="hiredate" value="#{userWizardMB.user.hireDate}" required="true" />
...
<p:commandButton value="Calculate days" icon="ui-icon-circle-check" 
    action="#{userWizardMB.calculateVacationDays}" 
    process="@this hiredate" update="vacationDays" />
```

#### See also:

- [Why was "immediate" attribute added to the EditableValueHolders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071512/why-was-immediate-property-added-to-the-editablevalueholders/13072172#13072172)

Comment: I added everything you suggested and my backing bean method is not being called anymore (userWizardMB.calculateVacationDays)?! I don't know why this happened, I read somewhere it could happen because of the validation of the other fields but even when they all have valid values it is not called :(

Comment: The given snippet works when placed in its own `<h:form>`. Give it a try first to exclude the other components which you omitted from the question from being the actual cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `process="@form"` (or `process="[the id of the calendar component]"` in the `commandButton`

`process="@this"` means that only the part of the model related to the commandButton (usually none) gets updated.

Comment: I tried process="@form" and the field was still null. When using process="hireDate" my backing bean method is no longer called...

Comment: Yes, sorry for not supplying that info.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but did you add `partialSubmit="true"` in the commandButton tag? At least in PrimeFaces 3.5, false is the default value of this attribute (see the PrimeFaces PDF documentation).