# JSF bypass selectOneMenu Validation Error

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, selectonemenu, validationerror

How do I skip the validation error of the selectOneMenu (combo box) of the JSF as shown below.

> form1:menu1: Validation Error: Value is not valid

the result when the value change of the combo box is correct and expected. I just want to bypass the validation error.

Comment: By the way, a `<h:selectOneMenu>` doesn't render a combobox, it renders a dropdownlist. A combobox is a textfield+dropdownlist in one (thus, an editable dropdownlist).

Answer (score -3):

Try using immediate = "true". It will bypass JSF level validations.

Comment: been googled and tried it but doesn't work. the error sometimes occur, sometimes don't

Comment: You misunderstood the purpose of `immediate="true"`. Carefully read the answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071512/why-was-immediate-property-added-to-the-editablevalueholders