# Bootsfaces button, how to perform actionListener

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I need use the button to call a method of a Managed Bean but it doen't have any ActionListener. I have something like this:

```
<b:button value="Tes1"  look="warning"size="lg"/>
```

I can't use the commandButton. Is there any way?
Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use a commandButton? You need the 'get'? Only solution is then to call some javascript that calls a remote action that does a 'post-redirect-get', but then you effectively created a commandButton that should do the same 'PRG'.... So

Comment: I need it to be out of a form, commandButton needs to be inside a form.

Comment: Why do you need it outside a form?

Comment: The button opens a `b:modal`. If I use a commanButton it performs a submmit and it doesn't show the modal window.

Comment: Then fix that problem!... Must be simple, since I use a commandButton all the time with opening modal dialogs/windows without any problems. Only not with BoostFaces but PrimeFaces, but they behave the same...

Comment: You mean not let it submmit? If I do that I woudn't perform an action in my managed bean.

Comment: Uuuhhh yes and no... Not submitting and fields does not mean you cannot call an action. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes

Comment: That's it! That helped me! I give you a point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question and the attempted solution, it was indeed approaching it from the wrong way. A `b:commandButton` can be used in the following way:

```
<b:commandButton value="Trigger (JSF passthrough)2" actionListener="#{managedBeanName.performCall}" immediate="true" update="@(#id_element)"/>
```

The key of this solution are `immediate=true` to scape validations and `update="@(#id_element)"` to update only a part of the screen. You could also use `update="@none"` to don't update the screen.

It needs to be inside a form.

Another option is to use `process="@this"` instead of `immediate=true`. In this way, it doesn't perform any validation since it does not submit any inputs from the form.

```
<b:commandButton value="Trigger (JSF passthrough)2" actionListener="#{managedBeanName.performCall}" process="@this" update="@(#id_element)"/>
```

Since the introduction of 'ajax' in JSF, this latter solution is more commonly used.

See also:

- [Should immediate="true" never be used when dealing with an AJAXified JSF 2.0 component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502326/should-immediate-true-never-be-used-when-dealing-with-an-ajaxified-jsf-2-0-com)

Comment: That skips validation but does sub,it the values.So you **do** want to submit? otherwise `process="this"` would be a better option. No validation and no submitting the values. Using this instead of the `immediate="true"` is better in modern ajax based solutions

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502326/should-immediate-true-never-be-used-when-dealing-with-an-ajaxified-jsf-2-0-com for the `immediate="true"` in combination with ajax  `b:commandButton` is ajaxified by default

Comment: It doesn't mater if it submits the form but I could add that to my answer so it's a more complete solution...

Comment: Improved answer

Comment: But what you describe now as the 'other' option, is, since 'ajax' exists,  the better option. It is not clear from this answer why you choose the less good one.